# datatables by ajax in codeigniter issue

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, datatables

I'm working on a project using codeigniter. I'm trying to use datatables to view data fetched by ajax. the network tab shows that the ajax returned values correctly but the function is marked as 404 and I get this error

```
"DataTables warning: table id=data - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7"
```

Here's the ajax in the network tab

[image]

I checked the response and it's correct. I've opened the ajax function like this: domain.com/module/controller/merchantsTable and I got correct data

```
{ "merchantsdata":[{"id":"6","email":"user@mail.com"},{"id":"7","email":"user2@mail.com"}]}
```

datatables code [updated: added 'processing' and 'serverSide']

```
<table id="data">
   <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>email</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>email</th>
    </tr>
   </tfoot>
   <tbody>

   </tbody>
</table>

//base_url refers to https://www.domain.com/

 $(function () {
    $('#data').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "<?=base_url()?>merchants/admin_merchants/merchantsTable",
        "columns": [
            { "merchantsdata": "id" },
            { "merchantsdata": "email"}
        ],
        "order":[0 , 'desc'],
        "lengthMenu": [[20, 50, -1], [20, 50, "All"]]
    } );
});
```

So how to fix this issue and make it work?

Comment: It is obvious that the response is actually NOT correct. Your data is present, but Datatables requires additional parameters in order to work. Have a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387356/codeigniter-with-datatables-ajax-populate)

Comment: worked without modifying the code. My mistake there was another folder in the root named 'merchants' so ajax didn't fetch data from the codeigniter route path but from the folder in the root. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
<table id="data">
   <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>email</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>

   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>email</th>
    </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked without modifying the code. My mistake, there was another folder in the root named 'merchants' so ajax didn't fetch data from the codeigniter route path (merchants module) but from the folder in the root which is wrong so I renamed the folder in the root and it worked.